# Find & List all directories under specific size in terminal? (Mac/Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, macos, terminal, find

I'm trying to list all directories in my Music Library that are smaller than 5mb. I tried the following command in terminal:

```
find /volume1/Music\ Library/ -type d -size -5M -print;
```

But it just listed thousands of directories, and the few I checked were of course much larger than 5mb. To come up with this command, I modified another command I use often to find empty directories:

```
find /volume1/Music\ Library/ -type d -empty -print;
```

For this one, after I verify that it's correct, I replace `-print;` with `-delete` and am looking for a similar experience based around directory size. I do not want automatic deletion for (hopefully) obvious reasons.

I'm doing this in Terminal through SSH to my Synology NAS which is running a Linux-based OS.

Comment: Using a single command in linux does not constitute programming - this clearly belongs over at either [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual of `find` command, the `-size` argument only works for **file**:

```bash
       -size n[cwbkMG]
              File uses n units of space.  The following suffixes can be used:
```

With `find`, `du` and `awk`:

```bash
find /volume1/Music\ Library/ -type d -exec du -ms {} \;| awk '$1 < 5'|cut -f 2-
```

This will list all directories with total contents smaller than 5M.

Edit:

If you want to delete the expected directories, you could add `| xargs -d \\n rm -rf` to the end of the command line:

```bash
find /volume1/Music\ Library/ -type d -exec du -ms {} \;| awk '$1 < 5'|cut -f 2- | xargs -d \\n rm -rf
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Then after I verify that this is correct, is there a way to add a delete function to that? Would it just be adding `| rm` or something to the end?

Comment: Also, is there a way to exclude all directories named "@eaDir"? (these annoying metadata directories that Synology's OS makes) And unfortunately, these are all getting listed as well.

Comment: I tried `find /volume1/Music\ Library/ -type d -not -path "./@eaDir/*" -exec du -ms {} \;| awk '$1 < 5'|cut -f 2-` but it still lists them.

Comment: @DasKraut Yeah, `| xargs rm` to the end. And `! \( -name '@eaDir' -prune \)` after `-type d`

Comment: If you want to delete the expected directories, you could add `| xargs -d \\n rm -rf` to the end of the command line. I have edited the answer.

Comment: This has worked for me. But I tried to replace the `$1 < 5` with `$1 < 1` to find all directories less than 1mb, but it gave me zero answers when I know there are tons of empty folders as well.